# MongoDB only using first entry

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord.js

I made an adventure command that searches for a persons profile in a Mongo database, then uses that info to calculate xp, coins, etc. I have made several other commands that use the database that work perfectly. This one, however, starts out fine by finding the correct document, but then when I try to populate the command with info from the called up document, it only pulls info from the first document in the database which belongs to my profile. So, everytime someone does adventure, it calculates everything based on my profile, then goes and adds it to the correct one. So they keep earning xp and coins but not according to their own profile info. See code below.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { Collection, MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require("discord.js");
const econModel = require('../models/econModel');
const humanizeDuration = require('humanize-duration');
const adventureCooldowns = new Collection();

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("adventure")
        .setDescription("Explore the world and find treasure"),

    execute(interaction){
        const Member = interaction.member;
        const memberHasAdvCooldown = adventureCooldowns.has(Member.id);
        function getRandomInt(min, max) {
            min = Math.ceil(min);
            max = Math.floor(max);
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
        }

        if(memberHasAdvCooldown){
            const remaining1 = adventureCooldowns.get(Member.id) - new Date();
            const remainingFormatted1 = humanizeDuration(remaining1, {
                language: 'en',
                round: true,
                units: ['h', 'm', 's'],
            })
            interaction.reply({ content: `You must wait ${remainingFormatted1} for the cooldown period to end before adventuring again.`, ephemeral: true});
        }

        if(!adventureCooldowns.has(Member.id)){
            econModel.findOne({ MemberId: Member.id }, async (err, Account) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                if(Account) {
                    console.log(`ID: ${Member.id}\n${Member.nickname}`);
                    const curXp = Account.Exp;
                    console.log(`Current XP: ${curXp}`);
                    const curLvl = Account.Level;
                    console.log(`Curent Level: ${curLvl}`);
                    const coinBonus = Account.coinBonus;
                    console.log(`Coin Bonus: ${coinBonus}`);
                    const xpBonus = Account.expBonus;
                    console.log(`XP Bonus: ${xpBonus}`);
                    const xpBase = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 50);
                    console.log(`Base XP: ${xpBase}`);
                    const xpLvlBonus = xpBase * curLvl;
                    console.log(`lvl XP: ${xpLvlBonus}`);
                    const xpTotal = Math.floor(xpLvlBonus * xpBonus);
                    console.log(`Total: ${xpTotal}`);
                    const Coins = getRandomInt(25, 200);
                    console.log(`Base coins: ${Coins}`);
                    const coinAdd = Math.floor(Coins * coinBonus);
                    console.log(`total coins: ${coinAdd}`);
                    const nextLvl = (500 * Math.pow(2, curLvl))/2;
                    console.log(`Next level: ${nextLvl}`);
                    const newExp = curXp + xpTotal;
                    if(nextLvl <= newExp){
                        econModel.collection.updateOne({ MemberID: Member.id }, { $inc: {Level: +1} });
                        econModel.collection.updateOne({ MemberID: Member.id }, { $inc: {Fowlercoins: +coinAdd} });
                        econModel.collection.updateOne({ MemberID: Member.id }, { $inc: {Exp: +xpTotal} });
                        interaction.reply({ content: `${Member.nickname}\nYou have leveled up! You are now level ${Account.Level + 1}!\nYou gained ${xpTotal} experience and found ${coinAdd} coins.`, components: [] });                        
                        econModel.collection.updateOne({ MemberID: Member.id }, { $set: {Next: nextLvl} });
                        adventureCooldowns.set(Member.id, Date.now() + 5000); //5000 is 5 seconds
                        setTimeout(() => adventureCooldowns.delete(Member.id), 5000);
                    } else{
                        econModel.collection.updateOne({ MemberID: Member.id }, { $inc: {Fowlercoins: +coinAdd} });
                        econModel.collection.updateOne({ MemberID: Member.id }, { $inc: {Exp: +xpTotal} });
                        interaction.reply({ content: `${Member.nickname}\nYou gained ${xpTotal} experience and found ${coinAdd} coins.`, components: [] })                        
                        econModel.collection.updateOne({ MemberID: Member.id }, { $set: {Next: nextLvl} });
                        adventureCooldowns.set(Member.id, Date.now() + 5000); //5000 is 5 seconds
                        setTimeout(() => adventureCooldowns.delete(Member.id), 5000);
                    }
                } else{
                    interaction.reply({ embeds: [new MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle("ECONOMY SYSTEM")
                        .setColor("#3be820")
                        .setDescription(`${interaction.member.nickname} does not have an account! To create one, use /economy start!`)
                        .setFooter({ text: 'Rum Bot 1.4.5' })]});
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the first thing it tries to use is Account.Exp from the called upon document, but it always fills it in with the first document in the database. Any idea how to stop this from happening? I have been trying for a week and have yet to make any progress.

Comment: "_but it always fills it in with the first document in the database._" What does that mean?What values are you getting and what values are you expecting instead? Where are the unexpected values being observed?

Comment: I should be getting different values for each individual person based on their current level and any bonuses they may have. However, when the command is run, it recognizes the individual, but then pulls data from my profile instead of the one belonging to the person that ran the command. I know this because I added console logs to show values of variables, as you can see in the code above. An example, a player of level 2 runs the command, it should read their profile and see they are level 2, loading that into curLvl. However, instead of reading the players level, it loads my level.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details. Still not clear to me if there's enough for us to help with. Based on my read, some client calls `execute` with an `interaction`. That `interaction` will have a `member` which will have an `id`. Your code then does a `findOne()` against some `econ` collection using that `id` value to match against the `MemberId` field. Assuming that the `interaction` parameter has the right value and the `econ` collection has `unique` values for `MemberId`s, then the code seems okay. What is the output that is proving that it 'recognizes the individual'?

Comment: ```console.log(`ID: ${Member.id}\n${Member.nickname}`);``` is what shows me who is calling the command, and has always been correct. It recognizes each individual and finds their profile. ```console.log(`Current XP: ${curXp}`);``` is the next parameter read but instead of reading it from the profile it just looked up, it reads it from my profile, which happens to be the first one in the database.

Comment: If you run `.count({ MemberId: <ID> })` against the `econModel` collection, where `ID` is the value of `Member.id` from the code, is the result more than `1`? If so, is that expected? If not and you run the `.findOne()` with the same filter, does the document contain the values that you expect? The code seems to look fine

Comment: I used the ```.count``` method as well as the ```.findOne()``` method. The count brought back 10 documents, despite telling it to find the one with a specific ID. The findOne query acted differently, though. Despite asking for a specific document (one that wasn't the first one in the collection) it would still return with the first document. Seems like the findOne query isn't operating correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The additional information from [the tests in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74073339/mongodb-only-using-first-entry?noredirect=1#comment130906311_74073339) is very helpful and informative.

It sounds like the actual data in your system is not as you expect it to be. So the system is probably behaving correctly, and the unexpected behavior is a consequence of the current data. Walking through parts of the comment in order will help this answer.

> I used the `.count` method as well as the `.findOne()` method. The count brought back 10 documents, despite telling it to find the one with a specific ID

The phrasing of "*despite telling it to find **the one** [document] with a specific ID*" here is interesting. Is there a [unique index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/) in the `econModel` collection on the `MemberId` field? If not, then there is no constraint in the database itself to enforce the implied claim that there should only be one document with a given value for the `MemberId` field.

> The findOne query acted differently, though. Despite asking for a specific document (one that wasn't the first one in the collection) it would still return with the first document. Seems like the findOne query isn't operating correctly.

Why are you assuming that the output of `findOne({MemberId: <val>})` is wrong? Did the document that was returned have a different value for its `MemberId` field than the one you queried with?

Based on your testing, I am under the impression that there are `10` documents in your `econModel` collection that have a value for their `MemberId` field that matches the one you are searching against. As next steps I would recommend examining all of them `(.find({MemberId: <val>})`), updating the values if they are not as expected, and creating a unique index on the field if you want the database to enforce uniqueness on that field going forward. May also need to also double check that there is not some bug in the code (as opposed to manual testing) which caused the discrepancy in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Currently, all 10 documents have a unique ```MemberID``` but I have not used the unique index method so that will probably force it to do what I want. After my previous comment I started experimenting with the ```findOne()``` query and when i told it to use ```MemberTag``` it worked perfectly. The unique index idea makes sense. I use the ```findOne()``` method in numerous other commands with no issue but none of them are as complicated as the adventure command. Thanks for all the help.